# I don't have persistence.xml in my project, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish-3

I have a problem with a Java EE project. I try to access my database but I get the following exception:

```
cannot Deploy SupinBank
Deployment Error for module: SupinBank:
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
    javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Moreover, I don't have any `persistence.xml` created in my project. Is this normal ?

Tell me if you want more details of the server.log.

Comment: You need to provide **a lot** more information for us to be able to help you. You don't need to have a `persistence.xml` if, for example, one is included via a jar file, or if you're not using JPA.

Comment: Here is the link of the logs http://fr.sourcepod.com/ezmvel64-6840

Comment: The problem is I'm using JPA :)

Answer (score 1):

From your log file:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve
>   EntityManagerFactory for unitName SupinBank-PU

If you use JPA you will need a persistence.xml file. The server log points out that it should have a persistence unit called SupinBank-PU. You need to provide this file in order to make you project running.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I'll try that. But when I create my persistence.xml file, should I reference it somewhere ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just put it in the correct folder, usually WEB-INF/classes/META-INF

Comment: No matter if I'm using an EJB project ?

Comment: You think of an EAR? Don't know, I am using my EJBs in a WAR.

Comment: Yes an EAR. I put my persistence.xml in the correct folder in my EJB project AND in my WebProject but I get the same error.

Comment: I think the problem may be that my EJB and my WAR aren't linked together (may be...) I'm trying to search on the web how to link them together.